# UIRefreshControl offset changes after loading new items to UITableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uirefreshcontrol

I added a UIRefreshControl to a UITableView.

The UITableView is under a top bar.

Everything works fine except when new items is being loaded. For example, if the table had 1 row and now, after reloading the data there is 2 rows.

After the table is being reloading, The UIRefreshControl offset isn't in the 0 position of the UITable but is adding the bar height to it so the user needs to pull not only the height of the UIRefreshControl but also the height of the top bar.

After loading again the same data, the UIRefreshControl is ok.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self setRefreshControl];

}
-(void)setRefreshControl
{
    refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc]init];
    refreshControl.tintColor=[UIColor redColor];
    [self.campaignsTableView addSubview:refreshControl];
    [refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refreshTable) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

}
```

Comment: How are you adding the new elements to the `tableView`? Do you call `reloadData` or `reloadRowAtIndexPath`?

Comment: I'm using reloadData